# SwiftUI How to use class with function in view

Tags: function, class, swiftui

I have this simple class:

```
import Foundation

class Utility {
    func somma(int1:String, int2:String) -> String {
        let totale = (Int(int1) ?? 0) + (Int(int2) ?? 0)
        let totale_Str = String(totale)
        return totale_Str
    }
}
```

and this simple view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var int1:String = "0"
    @State private var int2:String = "0"

    @State private var somma:String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Intero 1", text: $int1)
            TextField("Intero 2", text: $int2)
            Text("\(somma)")
            Button(action: {
                self.somma = Utility.somma(self.int1, self.int2)
            }) {
                Text("Somma")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but in the line `self.somma = Utility.somma(self.int1, self.int2)` I have this error `Instance member 'somma' cannot be used on type 'Utility'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?`
I have tried in different ways to eliminate the error without finding the solution.
How can I eliminate this error?

Comment: Either make the somma function static or create an instance of Utility. This is not SwiftUI related but a generic Swift design principle as in all other OO languages I know. Did you miss this or is there something SwiftUI related I overlooked?

Comment: Can you change my example to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.
Simply change:

`self.somma = Utility.somma(self.int1, self.int2)`

with:

```
self.somma = Utility().somma(int1: self.int1, int2: self.int2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Class function in Swift are preceded with `static` keyword, so if you want to use somma as class (i.e static) function you have to declare it like this:

`static func somma(int1:String, int2:String) -> String { //etc.`

Comment: I tried to do as you suggested, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Class:

```
import Foundation

class Utility:ObservableObject {
    var totale_Str : String = ""
    func somma(int1:String, int2:String) -> String {
        let totale = (Int(int1) ?? 0) + (Int(int2) ?? 0)
        let totale_Str = String(totale)
        return totale_Str
    }
}
```

View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var int1:String = "0"
    @State private var int2:String = "0"

    @State private var somma : String = ""
    @ObservedObject var utility = Utility()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Intero 1", text: $int1)
            TextField("Intero 2", text: $int2)
            Text("\(somma)")
            Button(action: {
                self.somma = utility.somma(int1: self.int1, int2: self.int2)
            }) {
                Text("Somma")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer? e.g. why is this better (or not) than Cesare Piersigilli's own answer.

Comment: I just wanted to solve the problem, and I didn't notice that he had solved it.